# d3js How to make Grids as `dotted` or `dashed`?

Tags: d3.js

I have made a simple line chart. I have added the grids to the `axis` but I would like to keep them as `dotted` or `dashed` so how can I do that?

```js
 var margin = {top: 20, right: 100, bottom: 30, left: 100},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var dataset = [
  {x: 0, y: 5},
  {x: 1, y: 8},
  {x: 2, y: 13},
  {x: 3, y: 12},
  {x: 4, y: 16},
  {x: 5, y: 21},
  {x: 6, y: 18},
  {x: 7, y: 23},
  {x: 8, y: 24},
  {x: 9, y: 28},
  {x: 10, y: 35},
  {x: 11, y: 30},
  {x: 12, y: 32},
  {x: 13, y: 36},
  {x: 14, y: 40},
  {x: 15, y: 38},
];

var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d){ return d.x; })])
    .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d){ return d.y; })])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .innerTickSize(-height)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(10);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left")
    .innerTickSize(-width)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(10);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)

  svg.append("path")
      .data([dataset])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
```

```css
.axis path,
  .axis line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
  }

  .line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }

  .tick text{
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .tick line{
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a property of the svg elements called *stroke-dasharray*.
Each time you have to set an style, use the .style() method

```
svg.append("path")
  .data([dataset])
  .attr("class", "line")
  .style("stroke-dasharray", "5 5")
  .attr("d", line);
```

It applies also for the axis

```
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .style("stroke-dasharray", "5 5")
  .call(xAxis)

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .style("stroke-dasharray", "5 5")
```

Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_stroking.asp) to see more properties or this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dts9r73e/1/)

If you want to set only for the internal grid, then you can do it using pure css

```
.tick line{
    opacity: 0.2;
    stroke-dasharray: 5 5; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, It works. But it's changing the `x` and `y` axis lines as well. just changing the grid alone not possible?

Comment: Unfortunately I don´t know if it is possible.

Comment: I figured it out. See my edited anwer please. Set the parameter in the css _.tick line_ that you defined before

Answer (score 1):

Set it using CSS and only apply it to `line` elements that are children of `tick` classed `g`:

```
.tick line{
  opacity: 0.2;
  stroke-dasharray: 5,5;
}
```

Example:

```js
 var margin = {top: 20, right: 100, bottom: 30, left: 100},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var dataset = [
  {x: 0, y: 5},
  {x: 1, y: 8},
  {x: 2, y: 13},
  {x: 3, y: 12},
  {x: 4, y: 16},
  {x: 5, y: 21},
  {x: 6, y: 18},
  {x: 7, y: 23},
  {x: 8, y: 24},
  {x: 9, y: 28},
  {x: 10, y: 35},
  {x: 11, y: 30},
  {x: 12, y: 32},
  {x: 13, y: 36},
  {x: 14, y: 40},
  {x: 15, y: 38},
];

var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d){ return d.x; })])
    .range([0, width]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d){ return d.y; })])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .innerTickSize(-height)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(10);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left")
    .innerTickSize(-width)
    .outerTickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(10);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)

  svg.append("path")
      .data([dataset])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
```

```css
.axis path,
  .axis line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
  }

  .line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width: 2px;
  }

  .tick text{
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .tick line{
    opacity: 0.2;
    stroke-dasharray: 5,5;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```